# How to configure build variants in Compose Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, compose-desktop

I have an app built with [Jetbrains Compose Multiplatform](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/compose-multiplatform/)

I need to generate two builds, i.e. `.msi`(Microsoft Software Installer) file.
One for internal use and one for external.
Example: `AppInternal.msi` and `AppExternal.msi`
Because I have some sensitive code which I want to package inside internal build only.

This can be achieved in Android via build variants and product flavours:

```
 productFlavors {
        internal {
            dimension "version"
            buildConfigField("boolean", "IS_INTERNAL", "true")
            ...
        }
        external {
            dimension "version"
            ...    
        }
    }
```

And then in source code we do something like:

```
if (IS_INTERNAL) {
    // Perform required steps
}
```

Please refer to this [official-documentation](https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants) for more details.

However, there are no such steps provided for Desktop for Compose.
So how can we have two builds inside Jetbrains Compose Multiplatform project ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/utopia-rise/kotlin-preprocessors) for incremental compilation or:
"I made a quick test with this

const val DEBUG = true
Then in Vector2:

```
 fun slerp(b: Vector2, t: RealT): Vector2 {
        if (DEBUG) {
            require(this.isNormalized() && b.isNormalized()) { "Both this and b vector must be normalized!" }
        }
        val theta: RealT = angleTo(b)
        return rotated((theta * t))
    }
```

Note: if (DEBUG) is line 402.

This leads to this bytecode:

```
L0
    ALOAD 1
    LDC "b"
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 402 L1
    NOP
   L2
    LINENUMBER 403 L2
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKEVIRTUAL godot/core/Vector2.isNormalized ()Z
    IFEQ L3
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKEVIRTUAL godot/core/Vector2.isNormalized ()Z
    IFEQ L3
   L4
    ICONST_1
    GOTO L5
   L3
    ICONST_0
   L5
    ISTORE 4
   L6
   L7
    ILOAD 4
    IFNE L8
   L9
   L10
    LINENUMBER 521 L10
   L11
    ICONST_0
    ISTORE 5
   L12
    LINENUMBER 403 L12
    LDC "Both this and b vector must be normalized!"
   L13
   L14
    LINENUMBER 403 L14
    ASTORE 5
   L15
    NEW java/lang/IllegalArgumentException
    DUP
    ALOAD 5
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Object.toString ()Ljava/lang/String;
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.<init> (Ljava/lang/String;)V
    ATHROW
   L8
    LINENUMBER 405 L8
    ALOAD 0
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKEVIRTUAL godot/core/Vector2.angleTo (Lgodot/core/Vector2;)D
    DSTORE 4
   L16
    LINENUMBER 406 L16
    ALOAD 0
    DLOAD 4
    DLOAD 2
    DMUL
    INVOKEVIRTUAL godot/core/Vector2.rotated (D)Lgodot/core/Vector2;
    ARETURN
   L17
    LOCALVARIABLE $i$a$-require-Vector2$slerp$1 I L12 L14 5
    LOCALVARIABLE theta D L16 L17 4
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lgodot/core/Vector2; L0 L17 0
    LOCALVARIABLE b Lgodot/core/Vector2; L0 L17 1
    LOCALVARIABLE t D L0 L17 2
    MAXSTACK = 5
    MAXLOCALS = 6
```

As we can see we have no operation for if line, and then all require expression code.

If I set

const val DEBUG = false
Then this leads to this bytecode:

```
 L0
    ALOAD 1
    LDC "b"
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 402 L1
    NOP
   L2
    LINENUMBER 405 L2
    ALOAD 0
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKEVIRTUAL godot/core/Vector2.angleTo (Lgodot/core/Vector2;)D
    DSTORE 4
   L3
    LINENUMBER 406 L3
    ALOAD 0
    DLOAD 4
    DLOAD 2
    DMUL
    INVOKEVIRTUAL godot/core/Vector2.rotated (D)Lgodot/core/Vector2;
    ARETURN
   L4
    LOCALVARIABLE theta D L3 L4 4
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lgodot/core/Vector2; L0 L4 0
    LOCALVARIABLE b Lgodot/core/Vector2; L0 L4 1
    LOCALVARIABLE t D L0 L4 2
    MAXSTACK = 5
    MAXLOCALS = 6
```

"
All require code is removed.

As we’re “dexifying” our jar for android and graal native image rely on jvm compiled bytecode, this should do the job !

https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/any-plans-for-having-conditional-compiling/1041/15